# Jwt Tymon laravel 5.1 + angularjs multiple async call error user_not_found

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.1, jwt

I'm using a Laravel Api and AngularJs frontend.
I have a problem with a middleware JWT.auth (tymondesign library) because if I do multiple asynchronous request from my frontend angularjs to backend api Laravel, sometimes (yes not always return error), return a 404 error "user_not_found" by middleware.

But doesn't return error in all request but in some.
I have no idea why this happens.

More clearly:

I have 4 ajax call from Angularjs Service that return a promise and in back end I have a route group under middleware JWT.auth

In my angularjs controller 4 call from 4 different services:

```
User.findAll().then(function(data){ $scope.users = data },function(err){});
Alert.findAll().then(function(data){ $scope.alerts = data},function(err){});
Workgroups.findAll().then(function(data){ $scope.workgroups = data},function(err){});
Usergroups.findAll().then(function(data){ $scope.usergroups = data},function(err){});
```

And backend example (I'm sorry for syntax):

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['jwt.auth']){
        Route::get('findAllUsers','userController@findAll');
        Route::get('findAlerts','alertController@findAll');
        Route::get('findAllWorkgroups','workgroupsController@findAll');
        Route::get('findAllUsergroups','usergroupsController@findAll');
    }
```

And someTimes one of this calls return exception from middleware Jwt : 404, "user_not_found".

For more information, I'm using Laravel 5.1 and Tymon JWT 0.5.6-master and The token is passed by header Authorization.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've edited your question a bit, I hope you'll find this an improvement. A well-formatted question is more likely to get good answers. Good luck!

Comment: Would you provide more details? When do you receive the error? Is it on specific Route? or is it completely random?

Comment: The error is on middleware, 
on 
/vendor/tymon/src/Middleware/GetUserFromToken.php and return this:
 

`return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.user_not_found', 'user_not_found', 404);`

like token not corrisponding to user. And the error is not for specific Route.
Sometimes for route AllUserGroups, sometimes for AllWorkgroups.
And someTimes nothing error.
I'm very confused.

Comment: I think there is a Bug on middleware, because sometimes when there are multiple ajax call, middleware return 404, even if the calls are the same:
example:
if in my controller I do 10 calls equals:
 User.findAll().then(.... );
On some of this calls backend middleware return error 404, so I think it is a bug.